# Ajax running java through windows batch file

Tags: java, ajax, json, windows, batch-file

I have a jQuery code calling $.ajax which takes the url of a windows batch file. The batch file calls a Java program that prints Content-type followed by a JSON stream using System.out.println(). I wrote a windows batch file that does the actual call, like

java -jar my.jar

Somehow, all the (Apache) server passes back is the echo of the command and nothing on the program output.

If I modify the batch to turn off the echo, like

```
@echo off
java -jar my.jar
```

OR

```
@java -jar my.jar
```

the "@" is passed to the client and causes an "Internal Server Error 500".

This must be a common problem. What is the standard solution here? I would appreciate some help here.

Thanks!!

Comment: *"I have an ajax code calling a java program on windows."* ***How?*** What server-side technology? What *feature* of that technology? What does the code doing it look like? That's the salient information here (or rather, *not* here). :-)

Comment: End up writing a C++ wrapper for java. Works out OK.